# Getting a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendTransaction')"

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I run the following command to run the project

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mumbai
```

then I get the folloing error massage

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendTransaction')
at ContractFactory.<anonymous> (C:\Users\geyuh\chainbattles\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1247:38)
at step (C:\Users\geyuh\chainbattles\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
at Object.next (C:\Users\geyuh\chainbattles\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
at fulfilled (C:\Users\geyuh\chainbattles\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

deploy.js:

```
    const main = async () => {
    try {
      const nftContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory(
        "ChainBattles"
      );
      const nftContract = await nftContractFactory.deploy();
      await nftContract.deployed();
  
      console.log("Contract deployed to:", nftContract.address);
      process.exit(0);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };
  
  main();
```

hardhat.config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
module.exports = {
 solidity: "0.8.10",
 networks: {
   mumbai: {
     url: process.env.TESTNET_RPC,
     accounts: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
   },
  },
   etherscan: {
     apiKey: process.env.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY
     }
  };
```

Comment: Can you check if the private key is imported correctly?